# How to make an in purchase app subscription

Tags: flutter

I need to make an in purchase app subscription, such that a user can use the app for 1 month after than he/she should pay every month

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase). Also [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@samarthagarwal_43146/in-app-purchases-in-flutter-f9ca7ee9e2ce) if you need help.